# Rails 3 bootstrap-sass-rails and modal display of form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling getting a simple modal dialog to display in my rails app. Here are the relevant files...

## Gemfile

```
group :assets do
...
  gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
...
end
```

## app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require "bootstrap"
//= require "bootstrap/modal"
//= require_tree .
```

## app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/modal";
```

## app/views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
    <%= link_to 'Modal', new_task_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
...
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

## app/views/tasks/_new.html.erb

```
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    **here comes whatever you want to show!**
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

## app/views/tasks/new.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>");
```

So this is just a simple app with a single model that I am trying to get my feet wet with. Right now the link will respond. The page fades, but I am not getting any content.

I've spent the last week messing around off and on trying to get this working wihtout much luck. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I believe it's because the request isn't responding with JS and instead is responding with HTML. If you look at the rails server log it should say Processing ... as HTML or as JS

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `modal()` on `$("#modal-window")`.  Update `app/view/tasks/new.js.erb` as:

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>").modal()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer vee, but no change in behavior after trying your change. I did some more experimenting, and it looks like the code <div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div> in my index file overrides everything. Does not matter what I do in new.js.erb, I get the same behaviour.